# Correctly initialising a Windows Event Log source in C#

Tags: c#, windows, event-log, event-viewer

In the [MSDN article for the EventLog Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog?view=netframework-4.8) it has the following block of code:

```
public static void Main(){
    // Create the source, if it does not already exist.
    if(!EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
    {
         //An event log source should not be created and immediately used.
         //There is a latency time to enable the source, it should be created
         //prior to executing the application that uses the source.
         //Execute this sample a second time to use the new source.
        EventLog.CreateEventSource("MySource", "MyNewLog");
        Console.WriteLine("CreatedEventSource");
        Console.WriteLine("Exiting, execute the application a second time to use the source.");
        // The source is created.  Exit the application to allow it to be registered.
        return;
    }
    // Create an EventLog instance and assign its source.
    EventLog myLog = new EventLog();
    myLog.Source = "MySource";

    // Write an informational entry to the event log.    
    myLog.WriteEntry("Writing to event log.");
}
```

I want to implement an `EventLog` instance correctly, as I'm developing an application that logs to Event Viewer. However, I can't find any mention of this requirement outside of this article, and my application appears to work well without enforcing this. Further, [the MSDN tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) for creating a service that uses the `EventLog` class doesn't enforce this requirement either.

What risks are inherent by not requiring the application to boot twice if the application uses the `EventLog` class? Is the worst risk that some logged info be lost, or is there some more subtle and ghastly behaviour that this could lead to?

Answer (score 0):

I have had an issue several years ago when the code that executed this did not have administrator rights.  I would then need to have those rights to create the event source.
Subsequent writes to that event log would work without administrator rights.